Prettier ignores tab width despite settings seem correct
I have this .prettierrc with "prettier": "^3.3.3" installed (package.json):
{
    "printWidth": 100,
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "trailingComma": "none"
}

Looked at other related questions which recommended not to use .editorconfig and uncheck the local configuration (application.json). Did all that, but the file is formatted on save with tab width set to 4 (despite settings being 2). Haven't tested if other settings are correct, but it seems.
From logs I can see my settings seem to be used:
["INFO" - 20:24:02] Extension Name: esbenp.prettier-vscode.
["INFO" - 20:24:02] Extension Version: 10.4.0.
["INFO" - 20:24:04] Formatting file:///Users/.../GitHub/leo-app/src/components/features/CaseCard.tsx
["INFO" - 20:24:04] Using config file at /Users/.../GitHub/leo-app/.prettierrc
["INFO" - 20:24:04] PrettierInstance:
{
  "modulePath": "/Users/.../GitHub/leo-app/node_modules/prettier/index.cjs",
  "importResolver": {},
  "callMethodResolvers": {},
  "currentCallMethodId": 2,
  "version": "3.3.3"
}
["INFO" - 20:24:04] Using ignore file (if present) at /Users/.../GitHub/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 20:24:04] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "typescript"
}
["INFO" - 20:24:04] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 20:24:04] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/Users/.../GitHub/leo-app/src/components/features/CaseCard.tsx",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "printWidth": 100,
  "useTabs": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "trailingComma": "none"
}
["INFO" - 20:24:05] Formatting completed in 434ms.

Tried to uninstall the extension and install again. Tried to restart VS Code.
Nothing seems to help. Any ideas why prettier isn't applying the settings which it says it would apply?

I just noticed it works fine in one file and not in another, all files .tsx.
